# Sending messages in circles.

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I am new to functional programming and just switched from haskell (Didn't like it much) to erlang (quite fond of it). As I am learning as an autodidact, I stumbled over [these Exercises](http://www.erlang.org/course/exercises.html) and started doing them.

I came as far as this problem:

> 1. Write a function which starts 2 processes, and sends a message M
>      times forewards and backwards between them. After the messages have
>      been sent the processes should terminate gracefully.

I resolved it like this and it works (maybe it can be done better; any comment highly appreciated):

```
-module (concur).
-export ( [pingpong/1, pingpong/2] ).

pingpong (Msg, TTL) ->
    A = spawn (concur, pingpong, ["Alice"] ),
    B = spawn (concur, pingpong, ["Bob"] ),
    B ! {A, TTL * 2, Msg}.

pingpong (Name) ->
    receive
        {From, 1, Msg} -> 
            io:format ("~s received ~p and dying.~n", [Name, Msg] ),
            exit (From);
        {From, TTL, Msg} ->
            io:format ("~s received ~p.~n", [Name, Msg] ),
            From ! {self (), TTL - 1, Msg},
            pingpong (Name)
    end.
```

The real problem is the next exercise:

> 2) Write a function which starts N processes in a ring, and sends a
>   message M times around all the processes in the ring. After the
>   messages have been sent the processes should terminate gracefully.

As I am not sending the message back to its originator, but to the next node in the chain, I somehow have to pass to the sending process the process of the recipient. So I imagined that the function would look something like this:

```
pingCircle (Name, Next) ->
...
    receive {TTL, Msg} -> Next ! {TTL - 1, Msg}
...
```

But how do I start this whole thing. When I spawn the first function in the circle, I still haven't spawned the next node and hence I cannot pass it as an argument. So my naive approach doesn't work:

```
First = spawn (concur, pingCirle, ["Alice", Second] ),
Second = spawn (concur, pingCirle, ["Bob", Third] ),
...
```

Also the approach of passing the spawn call of the next node recursively as a parameter to it predecessor, doesn't solve the problem how to close the circle, i.e. passing the last node to the first.

**The question is:**
How can I build this circle?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to your great answers, I managed to what I intended. Hence this question is solved.

One possible solution is:

```
-module (concur).
-export ( [pingCircle/3, pingCircle/2] ).

pingCircle (Names, Message, TTL) ->
    Processes = lists:map (fun (Name) -> spawn (?MODULE, pingCircle, [Name, nobody] ) end, Names),
    ProcessPairs = lists:zip (Processes, rot1 (Processes) ),
    lists:map (fun ( {Process, Recipient} ) -> Process ! {setRecipient, Recipient} end, ProcessPairs),
    Circle = lists:map (fun ( {Process, _} ) -> Process end, ProcessPairs),
    hd (Circle) ! {Message, TTL - 1, lists:last (Circle) }.

rot1 ( [] ) -> [];
rot1 ( [Head | Tail] ) -> Tail ++ [Head].

pingCircle (Name, Recipient) ->
    receive
        {setRecipient, NewRecipient} ->
            pingCircle (Name, NewRecipient);
        {Message, 0, Originator} ->
            io:format ("~s received ~p with TTL 0 and dying.~n", [Name, Message] ),
            if
                Originator == self () -> io:format ("All dead.~n");
                true -> Recipient ! {Message, 0, Originator}
            end;
        {Message, TTL, Originator} ->
            io:format ("~s received ~p with TTL ~p.~n", [Name, Message, TTL] ),
            if
                Originator == self () -> Recipient ! {Message, TTL - 1, Originator};
                true -> Recipient ! {Message, TTL, Originator}
            end,
            pingCircle (Name, Recipient)
    end.
```

Here is my [peer review link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/erlang-concurrency-in-circles).

Comment: +1 just for autodidactism. BTW, if you want constructive criticism about already-correct code, you can always try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: +1 to comment - that is pretty cool, thanks for the info!

Comment: +1 from me as well. This will help alot tackling this new langauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawn them first, then send them a start signal.

The start signal would be sent after all the processes are already running.

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing bit I needed to come up with my own solution. I updated my post.

Comment: I would appreciate your comments on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/erlang-concurrency-in-circles .

Answer (score 3):

This exercise has become a rite of passage for all erlang programmers. I gave a working solution to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135229/erlang-course-concurrency-exercise-can-my-answer-be-improved/5137770#5137770), along with an explanation that may be helpful.

Comment: +1 Very cool. I could have used that when I went through these!

Comment: Thank you so much. But after reading the word "rite of passage" I didn't dare look at your solution, but with @Michael 's input I passed the rite on my own. I updated my post and will upload my code to codereview.stackexchange.com and I would highly appreciate your comments.

Comment: I would appreciate your comments on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/erlang-concurrency-in-circles .

Comment: You are welcome - and congrats on completing the exercise. I'm impressed with what you wrote, given how new you are to the language. Overall your solution looks good - if I have specific comments I'll post them on codereview. The main difference between most solutions and mine is that I solved the slightly more difficult problem of having the ring be self-creating. I think my own solution could use some help in the readability department. If I come up with something better I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already came up with the answer here -> http://simplehappy.iteye.com/?show_full=true

Comment: Thank you very much, but after @Michael 's input, I preferred to keep on trying alone.

Answer (score 1):

My answer.

```
-module(con_test).

start_ring(Msg, M, N) ->
    [First|_]=Processes=[spawn(?MODULE, ring, []) || _ <- lists:seq(1,N)],
    First ! {rotLeft(Processes), {Msg, M*N}}.

ring() ->
    receive
        {_List, {Msg, Count}} when Count == 0 ->
            io:format("~p got ~s. Enough! I'm out.~n", [self(), Msg]),
            exit(normal);
        {[Next|_] = List, {Msg, Count}} when Count > 0 ->
            io:format("~p got ~s. Passing it forward to ~p.~n", [self(), Msg, Next]),
            Next ! {rotLeft(List), {Msg, Count-1}},
            ring()
    after 1000 ->
        io:format("~p is out.~n", [self()]),
        exit(normal)
    end.

rotLeft([])     ->  [];
rotLeft([H|T])  ->  T ++[H].
```